# Set a default user/password when in localhost

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

Is there a way to set a default user/password in web.config of a ASP.NET application **only** while it's running in localhost?
I've done some research and found some tags like "credentials" but I ended up with no results.

Thanks :D

Comment: I don't believe so, but if this is just for testing purposes, you could simply remove the Authorization section (which I assume your using) and re-add it at the time of go-live.

Answer (score 0):

If you take advantage of the publish option and the web.release.config file, you can have the credentials in the root config, and write a transform to remote it from the web config when published in release mode.